# clock animation in javafx programming

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, netbeans-7

i'm john i'm newbie in javafx programming. i have several querstion that i don't 
understand from this code (this code is using for create animation time) :

check this link for detail :
[check this out](http://blog.crisp.se/2012/09/24/oscarlantz/analog-clock-revisited#comment-4136)

first :
  there is two source code, what shouls i do? i'm really beginer in javafx programming, should i to create new package or new class or what? i'm currently use NET BEANS 7.2 ?

second :
  i choose new class than I copied your code into my "JAVAFX application project" (is that right ?) than i have 2 file first is **analogclock.java** and the second one is **analogclockwork.java** than i got 3 error,

in analogclock.java i found error in this code

```
- clockwork.hourHandAngle()
- clockwork.minuteHandAngle()
- clockwork.minuteHandAngle()

error -> "Cannot find symbol, symbol : method minuteHandAngle()
location: variable clockwork of type AnalogClock
----"
```

can you help me? i really need your help for my colage work. 
 **thanks for your help, i’m really appreciate it.**

note :
i think i create class in same package (javafxapplication 5 package in my case)
sorry i really new in javafx programming and actually i never use netbeans 7.2, i got this task from my lecture. i don't unserstand in your point 3,4,5 particularly in point 4, this is my project properties :

```
- AnalogClock
  - Source Packages
    - AnalogClock
      - AnalogClock.java
    - se.crisp.clock
      - AnalogClockwork.java
  -libraries
    - Default JavaFx Platform
```

is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*i think i create class in same package (javafxapplication 5 package in my case)*
  - You should not do that.

Seems you have missed a class in your package.

Do this :-

1. Create New `Project` lets name it `AnalogClock`
2. create new package under source packages and name it `se.crisp.clock` (from the above example)
3. Copy all the classes one by one and add under the above package. Use the same class name.
4. Add `javafx` related jars in project -> properties -> library
5. Clean and build & Run

Comment: sorry i really new in javafx programming and actually i never use netbeans 7.2, i got this task from my lecture. i don't unserstand in your point 3,4,5 particularly in point 4, this is my project properties :
- AnalogClock
  - Source Packages
    - AnalogClock
      - AnalogClock.java
    - se.crisp.clock
      - AnalogClockwork.java
  -libraries
    - Default JavaFx Platform

is that right?

Comment: can you give me step by step please?

Comment: [Get HelloWorld running](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm). Paste these [two files](https://gist.github.com/2658491) into the HelloWorld project in the default project directory (above the HelloWorld directory).  Right click on the Clock java file and select Run. Do the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) then get Per's clock sample running and post beginner Java questions at [Java Ranch](http://www.javaranch.com/) and JavaFX questions at [JavaFX forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1385)